# Adjusting parenthesis sizes for an axis label and shading under normal distribution curves

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot2`. Here is the code I am using and the output:

```
library(package=ggplot2)
normal <- function(mu, sigma, x){
1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-mu)/sigma)^2)
}
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=x, color=g)) + 
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(-2, 3.5), g=factor(1)), fun=normal, geom='line', 
                args=list(mu=0.5, sigma=2)) +   
  stat_function(data=data.frame(x=c(-2, 3.5), g=factor(2)), fun=normal, geom='line', 
                args=list(mu=1, sigma=2))  +           
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(from=-2, to = 3, by=1)) +
  ylab(expression(f(x) == frac(1, sigma~sqrt(2*pi)) ~ exp(-(frac(x-mu,sigma))^2))) + 
  scale_color_manual('',values=c('blue','red'), 
  labels=c(expression(N(mu == 0.5, sigma==2)),expression(N(mu == 1, sigma==2)))) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white'),
        panel.border=element_rect(fill=NA), 
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box = 'vertical',
        legend.position=c(0.85,0.85),
        legend.text.align=0) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 0.25))
```

I know that there is a `dnorm` function which can handle the density fine, but I wanted to at least know how to use `stat_function` for any functions I create.

Anyway, I digress. Here is the output:

[image]

Is there any way that I can resize the parenthesis in the y-axis label so that they fit over everything inside the `exp`?

Since I am new to `ggplot2`, any suggestions pertaining to writing cleaner code than what I have above would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Do you have access to Adobe Illustrator (or maybe you can do it in Microsoft Powerpoint)?

Comment: Also, save as SVG and Inkscape. If you want to do this for too many plots it's not the best alternative but for just a few could really help

Comment: I suspect that SO advice for questioners says to disaggregate unrelated questions (and I don't think the fact that you are using ggplot2 creates a relationship).. These two "things" are seeming unrelated. There are prior questions about shading under curves with answers that cover ggplot, lattice and base graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This demonstrates the use of `bgroup` which can be used to deploy scalable delimiters as described in ?plotmath:

```
plot( 1,1, ylab =expression(
           f(x) == frac(1, sigma~sqrt(2*pi)) ~ e^-bgroup("(", frac(x-mu,sigma), ")")^2) )
```

I also chose to use `e^expr` rather than "exp()" since it creates a more "mathematical" look, and also simplified the coding. (Needed to make the interactive device and the file device left margins bigger to accomodate the width of the ylab.

[image]